# I cannot add a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning JavaScript right now and I created a working function and now I want to call it inside another function but I cant

Here is my function

```
function findHeight1() {
  gravity = promptNum("Enter given gravity (If on earth g = 9.8)");
  time = promptNum("Enter given Time");
  height = 1/2 * (gravity * (time * time));}
```

I tried to add it inside a new function and it didn't work

```
function findPE2() {
  height = findHeight1();
  mass = promptNum("Enter given Mass");
  potentialEnergy = (mass * gravity) * height;}
```

Comment: `findHeight1` doesn't **return** anything - try `return 1/2 * (gravity * (time * time));`

Comment: also, try using `var` to declare variables in the function scope - as it is, all your variables are global - which is not a habit you want to get into

Comment: @JaromandaX any reason why `var` and not `let` or `const` ?

Comment: I use this `onEvent("gt", "click", function( ) {
  findHeight1();
  setScreen("output");
  setText("outputResult", "Height: "+height);
});`

Comment: I already create all variables at the beginning

Comment: @alfasin - baby steps :p

Comment: sorry, I was new to coding :<

Comment: Oh, ok ... but you say `height = 1/2 * (gravity * (time * time));` when you call `findHeight1` and `height = findHeight1();` in `findPE2` ... therefore, since there's no return value in the former, the latter sets `height = undefined` ... perhaps you just need to ADD `return height` to the first function - it's ugly, but will work

Comment: Worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return height` from `findHeight1` - but even so, since you're declaring your variables without `var`, `let` or `const`, they're being created as globals:

```
function findHeight1() {
  let gravity = promptNum("Enter given gravity (If on earth g = 9.8)");
  let time = promptNum("Enter given Time");
  let height = 1/2 * (gravity * (time * time));
  return height;
}
```